# Sublime text auto Java doc comment

Tags: java, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

How do I get Sublime Text to automatically generating Javadoc comments for methods? I tried looking around but amounted to nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to try [DocBlockr](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs).

It recognizes method parameters correctly and it lets you conveniently tab through the fields (like you do it when using Sublime snippets). But it is not flawless; it seems to have trouble with functions that return arrays, and it adds an `@param` block for constructors, too.

I guess it depends on how much automation you want.

(Type `/**` and press enter to trigger it. The gitHub readme has more details on how to use it)